# arp -a and route print

Tags: c#, windows, networking, network-programming

I need to write a program that displays this information:

- netstat
- TCP / UDP connections
- Information about the IP ipconfig /all
- arp-a
- route print

I already have most of them, but I have a problem with the `route print` and `arp -a`. I do not want to execute this command using `Process.Start()` because it does not look too spectacular:

```
Process p = new Process ();

p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "route";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "PRINT";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
TextBox1.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I would like to use a foreach loop to get the data into ListView or DataGrid columns. Has anyone ~ t be able to help me? How can I get this data into each column: Destination, Netmask, gateway, interface, metrics and permanent route? And in the case of ARP,
Internet address type of physical address?

Comment: Sorry, just saw that I forgot about the question about "arp -a". Take a look at the [GetIpNetTable2 Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814420(v=vs.85).aspx), fairly sure that that might be what you're looking for. Though not sure how easy it is to call from C#, might be some easier WMI way but I've never looked at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could probably just parse the text you retrieve to get out the values you want and put them in the `ListView` etc. However, I think that there are better ways to retrieve this and I think you'd be able to get out this information using the WMI class [Win32_IP4RouteTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you haven't used WMI before, you might be able to use the [WMI Code Creator v1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2CC30A64-EA15-4661-8DA4-55BBC145C30E&displaylang=en) to help you get started (I haven't used it myself, but I saw someone else suggesting it sometime).

The [WMI .NET Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx) would probably be useful too.

Comment: I can not use GetIPNetTable :(

Answer (score 4):

Imparted Thank you very much. I have already written with WMI CODER CREATOR who have directed and IPv4routetable the following code:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable");
        ListViewItem buf;

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            string destination = queryObj["Destination"].ToString();
            string mask = queryObj["Mask"].ToString();
            string metric = queryObj["Metric1"].ToString();
            string interfaceIndex = queryObj["InterfaceIndex"].ToString();
            string nexthop = queryObj["NextHop"].ToString();
            string protocol = queryObj["Protocol"].ToString();
            string type = queryObj["Type"].ToString();
            string status;
            if (queryObj["Status"] != null)
            {
                status = queryObj["Status"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                status = string.Empty;
            }


            buf = new ListViewItem(new string[] { destination, mask, metric, interfaceIndex, nexthop, protocol, status, type });
            list_route.Items.Add(buf);

        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Just do not know in which class I find information on arp-a can not find on google. If someone knew he was asking for the answer. If anyone has other useful aids such as WMI Coder Creator was grateful.

I found some information. About GetIpNetTable but I can not use this function in GUI applications, to pass the result to the listview. : (

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;

namespace GetIpNetTable
{
    class Program
    {
        // The max number of physical addresses.
        const int MAXLEN_PHYSADDR = 8;

        // Define the MIB_IPNETROW structure.
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct MIB_IPNETROW
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int dwIndex;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int dwPhysAddrLen;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac0;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac1;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac2;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac3;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac4;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac5;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac6;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
            public byte mac7;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int dwAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int dwType;
        }

        // Declare the GetIpNetTable function.
        [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll")]
        [Return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        static extern int GetIpNetTable(
           IntPtr pIpNetTable,
           [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.U4)]
             pdwSize ref int,
           bool border);

        // The Insufficient buffer error.
        const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The number of bytes needed.
            bytesNeeded int = 0;

            // The result from the API call.
            int result = GetIpNetTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref bytesNeeded, false);

            // Call the function, expecting an Insufficient buffer.
            if (result! = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            {
                // Throw an exception.
                throw new Win32Exception(result);
            }

            // Allocate the memory, do it in a try / finally block, to ensure code
            // That it is released.
            IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

            // Try / finally.
            try
            {
                // Allocate the memory.
                buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bytesNeeded);

                // Make the call again.If it did not Succeed, then
                // Raise an error.
                result = GetIpNetTable(buffer, ref bytesNeeded, false);

                // If the result is not 0(no error), then throw an exception.
                if (result! = 0)
                {
                   // Throw an exception.
                   throw new Win32Exception(result);
                }

                // Now we have the buffer, the have to marshal it. We can read
                // The first 4 bytes to get the length of the buffer.
                int entries = Marshal.ReadInt32(buffer);

                // Increment the memory pointer by the size of the int.
                IntPtr = new IntPtr currentBuffer(buffer.ToInt64() +
                   Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)));

                // Allocate an array of entries.
                MIB_IPNETROW[] table = new MIB_IPNETROW[entries];

                // Cycle through the entries.
                for (int index = 0; index < entries; index ++)
                {
                    // Call PtrToStructure, getting the information structure.
                    table[index] = (MIB_IPNETROW)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new
                       IntPtr(currentBuffer.ToInt64() + (index *
                       Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIB_IPNETROW)))), typeof(MIB_IPNETROW));
                }

                for (int index = 0; index < entries; index + +)
                {
                    IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(table[index].DwAddr);
                    Console.Write("IP:" + ip.ToString() + "\ t \ TMAC");
                    byte b;

                    b = table[index].mac0;
                    if (b < 0x10)
                    {
                        Console.Write("0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("");
                    }
                    Console.Write(b.ToString("X"));

                    b = table[index].mac1;
                    if (b < 0x10)
                    {
                        Console.Write("-0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("-");
                    }
                    Console.Write(b.ToString("X"));

                    b = table[index].mac2;
                    if (b < 0x10)
                    {
                        Console.Write("-0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("-");
                    }
                    Console.Write(b.ToString("X"));

                    b = table[index].mac3;
                    if (b < 0x10)
                    {
                        Console.Write("-0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("-");
                    }
                    Console.Write(b.ToString("X"));

                    b = table[index].mac4;
                    if (b < 0x10)
                    {
                        Console.Write("-0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("-");
                    }
                    Console.Write(b.ToString("X"));

                    b = table[index].mac5;
                    if (b < 0x10)
                    {
                        Console.Write("-0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("-");
                    }
                    Console.Write(b.ToString("X"));
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Release the elephant.
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me as expected. Thanks Man.