# Detect what VPN I'm connected to

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vpn

I'm currently working on an desktop tool to automate VPN connections to customers. I'd like to have a good way to know for sure I'm indeed connected to a VPN. I'm currently thinking about using the routing table as it's shown in netstat-rn and comparing it to the IP I should be connected to.

My question is, how would I be able to get these IP's in my C# application, or is there a better way to determine if I'm connected to a VPN.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so classic, I spend a couple of hours looking for the solution, and when I ask for help I find it myself.
For those who wonder, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946505/arp-a-and-route-print) as the solution.

```
try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable");
            ListViewItem buf;

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                string destination = queryObj["Destination"].ToString();
                string mask = queryObj["Mask"].ToString();
                string metric = queryObj["Metric1"].ToString();
                string interfaceIndex = queryObj["InterfaceIndex"].ToString();
                string nexthop = queryObj["NextHop"].ToString();
                string protocol =queryObj["Protocol"].ToString();
                string type = queryObj["Type"].ToString();
                string status;
                if (queryObj["Status"]!=null)
                {
                  status = queryObj["Status"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                   status = string.Empty;
                }


                buf = new ListViewItem(new string[] {destination,mask,metric,interfaceIndex,nexthop,protocol,status,typ});
                list_route.Items.Add(buf);

            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Anyway, thanks everyone who took the time to try and help me!

Comment: better include the necessary information in you post. So when the link goes dead people still find the answer here !